# Create hooks for automated testing

Tags: vue.js, integration-testing, vuejs2

QA guys recently complained they can't automate frontend testing. Because our html looks all the same from outside.
So as a lazy hack i did this

```html
<template>
    <div :role="$options.name">
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'VmComponentName'
}
</script>
```

Which just takes `name` from script and applies it to html. So that in browser you get:

```
<div role="VmComponentName">
     ...
</div>
```

Line `:role="$options.name"` goes in every component.

Is there any *DRY*er solutions? Please share.

---

#### Additional details

I'll explain in details what I am looking for.

Imagine I have `VmUserCreate` which is form that creates user. Test case is `Can create user`.

To automatically test it without role, I would have to use the following selector:

`.wrapper > .wrapper > .wrapper > .submit-button`

The test will be extremely brittle (will break a lot).

If I use roles I can use `[role="VmUserCreateForm"] .submit-button` selector. Which is many folds less brittle.

So basically, what I'm looking for is some sort of *template inheritance*. Where every component will attach role automatically. Because I have hundreds of components and pasting `$options.name` into every of them is meh.

[image: case html]

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    c1: {
      name: 'VmUserExplorer', 
      template: '<div class="wrapper" :role="$options.name"><slot></slot></div>'
    },
    c2: {
      name: 'VmUserList', 
      template: '<div class="wrapper" :role="$options.name"><slot></slot></div>'
    },
    c3: {
      name: 'VmUserCreateForm', 
      template: '<div class="wrapper" :role="$options.name"><slot></slot></div>'
    },
  }
});
```

```css
[role="someRole"] {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <c-1>
    <c-2>
      <c-3>
        <button class="button submit-button">Submit</button>
      </c-3>
    </c-2>
  </c-1>
</div>
```

Comment: You could create a property on Vue itself and refer to that.

Comment: @RoyJ and how would that influence html (template)?

Comment: Wherever you use `role`, you would use `Vue.role`.

Comment: @RoyJ Sorry. But I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to globally add `role="$options.name" to the root element of every component?

If so, I think you can get away with a global mixin which does this on `mounted` lifecycle hook.

For example, something like this:

```
Vue.mixin({
  mounted () {
    if (this.$el.setAttribute && this.$options.name) {
      this.$el.setAttribute('role', this.$options.name)
    }
  },
})
```